# Why is $\int_1^x(t+1)^3\ln(t+3)\,dt$ strictly increasing for $x\geq 1$?

Tags: derivatives

I have this function :

> $$f(x) = \int_1^x(t+1)^3\ln(t+3)\,dt$$

I need to justify why this function is strictly increasing for $x \geq 1$.

Can somebody please help me find the derivative in order to show that it is increasing?

I know that a function is increasing when the first derivative is greater than $0$.

Comment: next time use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your questions or else it will be hard to read and you'll end up getting little to no answers

Comment: Use the fundamental theorem of calculus!

Comment: Sara:  In keeping with @TheIntegrator 's suggestion, click on edit, so you can view the mathjax formatting of your initial post.

Comment: If you need to prove it's strictly increasing, it suffices to prove that the first derivative is strictly positive for all $x \geq 1$. What is this derivative?

Comment: Also when you want to know how a certain equation is formatted right click on it and view it in TeX code to understand

Comment: using the fundamental theorem of calculus would that mean that i have to subsitute x into t?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\textbf{Hint: }$ Use the [Leibnitz Integral Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) to differentiate both sides of the equation $$f(x) = \int_1^x(t+1)^3\ln(t+3)\,dt$$  Hence, $$f'(x)=(x+1)^3\ln(x+3)$$
Also note that $\ln(x+3)>0$ and $(x+1)^3>0$ for $x\ge 1$. $$$$What does $\ln(x+3)>0$ and $(x+1)^3>0$ for $x\ge1$ imply about the sign of $f'(x)=(x+1)^3\ln(x+3)$ for $x\ge1$?

Well, it implies that for $x\ge 1$, $f'(x)>0$. Hence $f(x)$ is $\textbf{ strictly increasing}$ for $x\ge1$.
$$$$
$\textbf{Edit: }$ $$$$How do we know that $\ln(x+3)>0$ for $x\ge 1$? $$$$Put $y=x+3$, hence $\ln(x+3)=\ln(y)$. 
$$$$
Now, [$\ln(y)$ is an increasing function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm#/media/File:Log.svg) in its domain ie the value of $\ln(y)$ is increasing for successive values of $y$.

Also clearly $\ln(y)>0$ for $y>1$
$$\Rightarrow \ln(x+3)>0\text{ for } x+3>1$$

Thus, $\ln(x+3)>0$ for $x>-2$. $$$$Hence for any value of $x$ which is greater than $-2$, $\ln(x+3)>0$. $$$$Similarly one can prove that $(x+1)^3>0$ for $x>0$ (and consequently for $x\ge1$).

Comment: It implies that it is increasing. Thank you . However i don't seem to understand what the question asks when it says 'strictly increasing for x≥1' . I don't get how it is related to the problem.

Comment: Would that mean that once i found the derivative i need to subsitute 1 into these two: (x+1)3 ln(x+3)?? And then i see if they are positive ?

Comment: That would mean that i need to subsitute 1 into f ' (x)... Correct??

Comment: To address your first doubt: $$$$What is meant by $f(x)$ is $\textbf{strictly increasing}$? It means that for any increase in $x$, $f(x)$ has a corresponding increase.$$$$ If it is mentioned that $f(x)$ is $\textbf{non-decreasing}$, it implies that for any increase in $x$, $f(x)$ may or may not increase, but will certainly not decrease.

Comment: The statement $y=f(x)$ is strictly increasing for $x\ge 1$ implies that for any increase $dx$ in $x$, there is a corresponding increase $dy$ in the value of $f(x)$ as long as $x$ is greater than $1$. Simply put it means that the values of $f(x)$ keep increasing for successive values of $x$ as long as $x\ge 1$.

Comment: So would i said practically makes nonesense, i dont have to subsitute 1 into the derivative

Comment: First we have established that $f'(x)=(x+1)^3\ln(x+1)$. We now have to establish that the value of $f'(x)$ is greater than $0$ for any $x$ as long as $x\ge 1$

Comment: In other words, we have to show that for putting any particular value of $x$ (as long as $x\ge1$) into the expression for $f'(x)$, the value of $f'(x)$ is greater than 0.

Comment: @SaraSalvante I've edited my answer to adress your doubts. Kindly consider upvoting and accepting the answer in case it suits your question.